# Crystal Reports: multi-value parameter to filter on substring value

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have a Crystal Reports 2008 file with a string parameter that accepts multiple values. I need to use this in the record selection. I know generally you can do something like

```
{MyTable.MyField} In Join( {?MyParam}, "," )
```

but I need users to enter values that may appear in a much longer field value, i.e., by substring. I tried

```
NumberVar index;
For index := 1 To UBound( {?MyParam} ) Do (
    {?MyParam}[index] In {MyTable.MyField}
)
```

and while it doesn't throw an error, it doesn't seem to have any effect on record selection (that is, the report displays the same number of records regardless).

To be more specific, say `MyTable` has three records, and `MyField` contains the text `Red Blue Green`, `Green Yellow Purple` and `Red Yellow Orange` respectively. With the parameter, the user should be able to type the values `red` and `blue` in order to filter down to the first and third records.

Comment: You don't need to manually delimit the values, Crystal Reports does it automatically: `{MyTable.MyField} IN {?MyParam}`.

Comment: In you second example, the record-selection formula won't be passed to the database (the logic is too complex). 

As a result, you will see the same number of records being read from the database.  It will, assuming that your logic is correct, discard records as they are read from the database (`WhileReadingRecords`, it is termed).

Comment: I should have said "displays" rather than "reads in" (updated). The same records are displayed either way. `{MyTable.MyField} In {?MyParam}` works for straight equality, but not if I want to match based on substrings.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom formula to compare two arrays for over-lapping values:

```
//Array_Overlap
Function (Stringvar Array a0, Stringvar Array a1)

    Local Numbervar i;
    Local Numbervar j;
    Local Booleanvar found:=false;

    For i := 1 To Ubound(a0) Do (
        For j := 1 To Ubound(a1) Do (
            If a0[i]=a1[j] Then (
                found:=true;
                Exit For;
            )
        )
    );

    found;
```

Reference it in your record-selection formula (RSF):

```
// space delimited
AND Array_Overlap( Split({MyTable.MyField}, " "), {?MyParam} ) = TRUE
```